# Get the pending value of the form control on button click in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form control that I have set up to update on blur. The user can submit the form by clicking a button or by pressing a keyboard shortcut key to submit the form (F3 in our case). The problem I have is when the user changes the value in the input field (and without tabbing off [which would update the form control's value]), presses F3, the form control is not updated with the latest value. In Chrome dev tools, I see the value in the _pendingValue of the form control. But how do I programatically trigger the blur event so that the _pendingValue updates the value of the form?

Comment: Why is the blur event needed? Can't you bind your input to the reactive form?

Comment: I have some validations that will show a modal dialog with the error message. I don't want the modal to be shown every time the user types something.

Comment: Could you show the dialog on form submit (if the form is invalid) instead of on blur? Or you could bind the input to the form and add a custom validator that prevents the form submission if the conditions that would cause the dialog to show are true. That way you could still show the dialog on blur if you really need to

Comment: The requirement is to show the modal as soon as possible. In this case, it is a date field and the user should not be able to enter a future date. If they do enter a future date, then a modal with the error should be shown as soon as they tab out or submit the form using F3 or the button. The problem is when they edit the date and using the keyboard shortcut, it does not update the form with the current value.

Comment: Then I'd bind the input to the form and add a custom validator. That way the form is always in sync and you can show your dialog on blur but the form only submits if there are no errors. I'd have to see your code to give you an example

Comment: For now I have programatically called the blur event on the document.activeElement so that the form is updated with the current value. But for some reason, document.activeElement.blur() does not work. I have to create a blur event and call document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(). This simulates the blur event and the form gets updated.

Comment: If you absolutely must do it that way, can't you just call the function that "blur" calls instead of raising the blur event?